# Reference Worksheet using a cell as the name

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to use text in a cell as a reference in another formula to a worksheet. Is this possible to be done?

The text in Cell F4 is changing as its formula dependant.

e.g:

- In Cell F4 i have the text P10.
- I have a worksheet with the name P10
- In another cell i am trying to reference Cell F4 as the Worksheet name.
- So my formula is "='F4'!M4" (instead of "='P10'!M4")

However this just errors or opens a file explorer to System 32.

I have tried using a defined name, formula or external reference and can't get this to work.

Comment: Try `=INDIRECT("'" & F4 & "'!M4")`  [INDIRECT Formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook This works however when i drag the formula down, the M4 doesnt increment.

Comment: You didn't say you wanted it dragged down.  M4 will stay static as it's just text within the function.  You could use `ROW()` to get a number that increments.  `=INDIRECT("'" & $F$4 & "'!M" & ROW())` - this will return the row that the formula is written in, so you may want to use `ROW()+1` depending on where your target data is.